# Atheros AR9271 for TP Link TL-WN721N not working on Kali Linux distribution

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, wlan

I'm trying to make my TP-LINK TL-WN721N Wireless USB card to work on Kali linux distribution when started within Virtual Box.

I've been reading in Google and trying different things but nothing works. So, here is the output for lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
As you can see, the first one Atheros Communications... is the WLAN card.
```

The driver is in

```
root@kali:/lib/firmware# ls -l htc*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72684 Aug 27 14:21 htc_7010.fw
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 50980 Aug 27 14:21 htc_9271.fw
```

If i understood correctly it is the second one.

Here is the dmesg log:

```
[  983.927278] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271
[  983.927282] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
[  983.927284] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 WLAN
[  983.927285] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: ATHEROS
[  983.927286] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 12345
[  983.961188] usb 1-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw requested
[  983.961480] usb 1-1: firmware: direct-loading firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw
[  984.992934] usb 1-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware - ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw download failed
[  984.992934] usb 1-1: ath9k_htc: USB layer deinitialized
```

Any help will be very much appreciated,

Fernando

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same card. You need to install the firmware-atheros drivers and add this entry to /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf.

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=0
```

After that, simply do a `systemctl restart NetworkManager` and voila!